# Object.keys() returns properties

Tags: javascript

From [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18202926/8388337) he said `Object.keys()` get properties defined on the object itself (the ones that return `true for obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` but below code returns `4 keys` and also producing an error which is confusing to me.

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    console.log("No of keys: ", Object.keys(buttons).length);
    for ( var i in Object.keys( buttons ) ) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function() {
            this.parentElement.remove();
            console.log(this.id);
        };
    }
})();
```

```html
<div>Some entry here
    <button id="0" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>Another entry here
    <button id="1" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

how to do this properly in javascript?

Comment: `but below code returns 4 keys` nope, 2 in firefox

Comment: i am using chrome.

Comment: It's 4 in Chrome and 2 in Firefox. Because the ids are `0` and `1` the HTMLCollection has a collision between the index-based keys and id-based keys. I'm guessing that because the indexes are numbers Chrome is treating them as not equal to the string ids, though `Object.keys` is then converting them all to strings, so you end up with `['0', '1', '0', '1']`.

Comment: ewww. chrome returns `Object.keys() == ["0", "1", "0", "1"]` for `document.getElementsByClassName('remove')` - how special is that! - even with the above explanation, why would chrome be so wrong? (note, it has NOTHING to do with the id's being 0 and 1)

Comment: try `for ( var i in Object.keys(Array.from(buttons)))` - chrome doesn't mess that up

Comment: @JaromandaX that is also useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how you'd loop over the `buttons` from your original code using a `for` loop:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

    console.log(buttons);
    
    for (var index = 0 ; index < buttons.length ; ++index) {
        buttons[index].onclick = function() {
            this.parentElement.remove();
            console.log(this.id);
        };
    }
})();
```

```html
<div>Some entry here
    <button id="a" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>Another entry here
    <button id="b" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Note that the `buttons` object is an `HTMLCollection`. This exposes elements by both index and id. In your original example your ids were `0` and `1`, which is quite confusing in this case because it causes them to clash with the indexes. `Object.keys(buttons)` was returning `['0', '1', '0', '1']`, which is a bit odd, presumably because of some number/string shenanigans. I've changed the ids in my example to `a` and `b` so now `Object.keys(buttons)` would be `['0', '1', 'a', 'b']`.

Comment: That's actually the correct answer to why it doesn't work, a HTMLCollection exposes the elements both by index and ID, and the OP's strange ID's was misleasing, making it look like the elements where exposed by index twice in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Not only for this `true for obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` condition, but also one of the properties attributes called `enumerable` must be also set to `true`.

What about your code. Lets see what is `buttons` actually. You see that this is an object, which contains 7 properties. Only 4 properties in Chrome are shown, because they are enumerable

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
    console.log(buttons);
 
})();
```

```html
<div>Some entry here
    <button id="0" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>Another entry here
    <button id="1" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

So when you try to execute this code

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

    for ( var i in Object.keys( buttons ) ) {
        console.log(i);
    }
 
})();
```

```html
<div>Some entry here
    <button id="0" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>Another entry here
    <button id="1" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

it actually get's the `indexes` of the array returned from the `Object.keys` which are `1,2,3,4`, but you don't have a property with name `2, 3, 4` in your `buttons` object. So why you get the error. Use `forEach` function to iterate over each property and add your event listeners.

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(buttons, button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.parentElement.remove();
            console.log(this.id);
        });
    });
 
})();
```

```html
<div>Some entry here
    <button id="0" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
<div>Another entry here
    <button id="1" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain why elements are repeated/duplicated in console

Comment: @Srinivas this is an Chrome issue, if you look it in Firefox you will see two.